# libclntsh.so.12.1: undefined symbol: ons_init_wconfig_ctx

Tags: python, oracle, oracleclient

i have a python script which was running fine.But now i am getting the below error:

```
 symbol lookup error: /oracle-client/12.1.0.1/x86_64-linux-2.6-libc6/libclntsh.so.12.1: undefined symbol: ons_init_wconfig_ctx
```

Can someone help with what is required to overcome this.
Thanks.

Comment: This is nothing to do with an Oracle database; it is just to do with the client application you are connecting to via python. Please stop including the Oracle tag as it is not relevant.

Comment: I disagree: it is Oracle related so the oracle tag is appropriate and is how I track questions to answer.

Comment: @svk Do you have multiple versions of Oracle libraries installed?  How do you set your library search path?  Did the order of directories in the path change?  What version of the Python driver are you using?  (Update your question with this information)